# double commit - svn hook

Tags: linux, svn, python-2.7

I got a task form our developers.
If the developers commit something to into the

```
http://svnserver/RepositoryA/directory1/directory2
```

The hook should put the same modification into the

```
http://svnserver/RepositoryB/directory1/directory2
```

too

I have a little experience in python 2.7 but I don't know how I should start the implementation.
Someone could help me?

Comment: What's this have to do with Python? You want to write the hook in Python?

Comment: yes I would like to write a hook in python what can add the same modifications to the second repository

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail, it looks like you're going about this the wrong way, and this is an example of an "XY Problem" (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You probably want the "svnsync" command, to mirror one repository at a different location:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnsync.html

If creating a mirror of RepositoryA is NOT what you are trying to do, please give more detail on the problem you are actually trying to solve, instead of the solution you think will solve your problem.